# I have a white page that won't delete before chapter

Tags: chapters, page-breaking

Hello could somebody help me with this code
thanks,
edit: the \documentclass[a4paper, 12pt,openany]{report} solution doesnt work for whatever reason
Also the bibliography doesn't show and i dont know why

````
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{report}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{eurosym}


\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{url}
\usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor}
\usepackage{hyperref}
%pour la mise en page des tableaux
\usepackage{array}

\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{abstract}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[top=2cm, bottom=2cm, left=2cm, right=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{datetime}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{4}
\newdateformat{monthyeardate}{%
  \monthname[\THEMONTH] \THEYEAR}
  \usepackage{lettrine}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{csvsimple}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{array}

\usepackage[breakable, skins]{tcolorbox}


% Boîte type générique
\newtcolorbox{boitetype}[4][]{enhanced, breakable, before
upper = {\parindent17.6pt}, beforeafter skip =
\baselineskip, colframe = #3, colback = #4, boxrule = 2pt,
arc = 4mm, fonttitle = \bfseries, title = {#2}, coltitle
= black, #1}



\newenvironment{boite}[3][]{\begin{boitetype}[#1]{#2}{#3}{white}}{\end{boitetype}}




\begin{document}
\begin{titlepage}
\newcommand{\HRule}{\rule{\linewidth}{0.5mm}} 
\begin{center} 
\includegraphics[width = 0.45\linewidth]{fms.jpg} \\[1.5cm]
\textsc{\LARGE{}Université de médecine ibn el jazzar sousse} \\[1.5cm]
\textsc{\Large{}premier cycle des études médicales} \\[0.5cm] 
\textsc{\large{}Médecine préventive et communautaire} \\[0.5cm] 
\HRule \\[0.6cm]
{\huge\bfseries{}Automédication chez les étudiants en médecine
par antibiotiques } \\[0.25cm]
\HRule \\[1.5cm]
\begin{minipage}{0.45\linewidth}
\begin{flushleft}
\author{Nom1 \and Nom2 \and Nom3}
\Large\textit{Auteurs :} \\
 Med aziz \textsc{rahmeni}\
 
 Achraf \textsc{jabrallah}\
 
 Mohamed \textsc{agrebi}\
 
 Wissem \textsc{dayeh}\
 
 Emna \textsc{baccari}\
 

 Feres \textsc{abderrahim}\
 


Abdelaziz \textsc{karaa}
 

\end{flushleft}
\end{minipage}
\hfill
\begin{minipage}{0.45\linewidth}
\begin{flushright}
\Large\textit{Superviseur :} \\

Dr.\textsc{chelli} 
\end{flushright}
\end{minipage} \\[2cm]
\monthyeardate\large\today \\[2cm] 

\end{center}
\vfill 

\end{titlepage}

\clearpage\setcounter{page}{2}
\tableofcontents


 \chapter*{Problématique}
 \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Problématique}
    \begin{enumerate}
    
    \item \begin{large}
\underline{Automédication :}
\end{large}\\



L'automédication consiste, pour les utilisateurs, à soigner leurs pathologies en utilisant des médicaments dûment autorisés, sans avis médical préalable, ni le conseil du pharmacien d'officine.
C'est une pratique très répandue chez les étudiants et particulièrement ceux des filières médicales.

L’étudiant consomme les médicaments notamment les antibiotiques selon
ses propres croyances, informations 
dont il a entendu de ces tuteurs….

L’automédication est aujourd’hui un sujet qui intéresse de nombreux chercheurs.




\item \begin{large}
\underline{Antibiotiques :}
\end{large}\\


Les antibiotiques sont des médicaments puissants dont la prise peut entraîner des effets secondaires et provoquer des réactions allergiques



\item \begin{large}
\underline{Facteurs de risques :}
\end{large}\\

$\bullet$ Raison économique

$\bullet$ La souffrance des étudiants en même temps l’absence d’une préoccupation de leurs sante 

$\bullet$ Leurs confiance en eux vu leurs connaissances pharmacologiques

$\bullet$ Les amplitudes horaires importantes entraînant une fatigue ,les violences psychologiques, le manque de soutien des supérieurs hiérarchiques, l’insuffisance d’encadrement.

\item \begin{large}
\underline{Revue de littérature :}
\end{large}\\

\end{enumerate}




$\bullet$ Une étude \cite{1} descriptive transversale a été menée auprès de 177 participants à l’étude (20 $+-$ 3 ans) entre décembre 2019 et février 2020 à l’aide d’un questionnaire.

L’étude a été menée dans le Département des sciences infirmières du Collège Universitaire de la province de Farasan, un institut d’enseignement
de premier plan de l’Île de Farasan affilié à l’université de Jazan, KSA.
les pratiques d’automédication étaient élevées chez les étudiants en sciences
infirmières (n = 154 participants, $87\%$).

Les élèves avaient des attitudes très positives envers l'automedication et la majorité des participants étaient au courant des effets indésirables.
Les raisons les plus citées pour l'utilisation des analgésiques sont des maux de tête ou des douleurs de menstruations, fièvre, migraine et rhume et toux.

 L’azithromycine était le seul antibiotique utilisé par les participants (n = 4 participants, $2\%$).
 
 
De plus, l’automédication était significativement associée à l’année de l’étude.


Un nombre important de participants à cette étude 
ont indiqué que leur horaire scolaire est trop chargé donc ils n'ont pas le temps de consulter un médecin ou prendre rendez-vous à l'hôpital.


La majorité des participants à l'étude ont répondu que leur maladie  n'était pas suffisamment grave pour mériter de consulter un médecin.

il a été illustré que la raison la plus courante d'utiliser l’automédication est la connaissance que l’élève a des maladies et des médicaments.


les étudiantes en soins infirmiers comprennent que le traitement par soi-même doit être sincèrement évité
parce que tout usage inapproprié d'un médicament peut entraîner divers problèmes de santé graves.\\















$\bullet$ Une étude \cite{2} transversale descriptive a été réalisée parmi les étudiants de premier cycle en médecine et en dentaire de la première année à la cinquième année à l'Institut des sciences de la santé BP Koirala du 1er juin 2018 au 30 août 2018.

 L'approbation éthique a été obtenue auprès du comité d'examen institutionnel (IRC/1210/018).
 
  Un échantillonnage complet a été effectué.Les données ont été recueillies à l'aide d'un questionnaire auto-répondant, semi-structuré et analysé. 
  
  
\underline{Résultats :} Sur un total de 558 étudiants, la prévalence de la pratique de l'automédication de différents antibiotiques était de 285 ($51,1\%$) au cours de l'année écoulée.

 Parmi les étudiants pratiquant l'automédication, 152 ($53,3\%$) étaient des hommes. Le médicament le plus couramment utilisé en automédication était l'azithromycine, 80 ($28,1 \%$), et la condition médicale la plus courante pour l'utilisation d'antibiotiques en vente libre était le traitement du mal de gorge avec écoulement nasal, 129 ($45,3 \%$).
 
  La principale source d'approvisionnement en antibiotiques non prescrits était les pharmacies de détail 157 ($55,1\%$).\\
  
$\bullet$ Une enquête \cite{3} transversale a été menée dans la seule université médicale publique du Mali. Le questionnaire explorait les connaissances des étudiants en médecine sur les antibiotiques, et les comportements de santé pour les maladies auto-limitantes. Les données ont été analysées dans SPSS.


\underline{Résultats :} Un total de 446 étudiants en médecine ont rempli le questionnaire. 
 
Le score moyen des connaissances était de 4,12 sur 10. Les étudiants ayant une expérience clinique ont obtenu de meilleurs résultats (4,79 vs 3,74, p< 0,01) ; 391($87,7\%$) étudiants en médecine ont déclaré avoir eu des maladies auto-limitantes au cours de l'année écoulée. 

Parmi eux, 197 ($50,4\%$) ont consulté un médecin, dont 160 ($81,2\%$) se sont vu prescrire des antibiotiques : 151 étudiants en médecine se sont traités eux-mêmes, dont 121 ($80,1\%$) ont utilisé des antibiotiques.











\chapter*{Cadre conceptuel}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Cadre conceptuel}
\section*{Déterminants de la santé}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Déterminants de la santé}
\subsection*{1. Mode de vie: }
\addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{1. Mode de vie}
Un mode de vie qui pousse a cette pratique peuvent être:

$\bullet$ les connaissances: les étudiants ont une connaissance en pharmacologie qu'il ne cesse a utiliser.


$\bullet$ la gestion du temps: une mauvaise gestion du temps par ces étudiants vu le nombre élève des heures passé a étudier

\subsection*{2. Facteurs biologiques: }
\addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{2. Facteurs biologiques}
Des  facteurs biologiques peuvent influencer cette pratique tel que:

$\bullet$ Des maladies métaboliques tel que le diabète,

$\bullet$ Des maladies héréditaires comme les maladies auto-immunes favorisants une immunodépression,

$\bullet$ Des infections à répétition,

$\bullet$ La dépression et l’anxiété (mesurée à l’aide de l’échelle HAD),

$\bullet$ Des désordres liés a des pratiques illicites comme le sexe et la drogue.
\subsection*{3. Facteurs environnementaux: }
\addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{3. Facteurs environnementaux}
Des facteurs de l’environnement peuvent influencer cette pratique:

$\bullet$ La facilité d’accès aux médicaments (pas de nécessité d’une ordonnance médicale),

$\bullet$ L’automédication en tant que phénomène social.

\subsection*{4. Facteurs liés au système de soin: }
\addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{4. Facteurs liés au système de soin}
Le système de santé peut avoir des influences sur l’automédication:

$\bullet$ L’insatisfaction envers le corps médical.


$\bullet$ Les facteurs économiques. 



\chapter*{Objectif de recherche}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Objectif de recherche}

Déterminer la prévalence des étudiants en médecine qui optent pour l'automédication.
Déterminer les facteurs prédisposant à ce phénomène.\\

{\let\clearpage\relax\chapter*{Question de recherche}}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Question de recherche}
Quelle est la prévalence des étudiants en médecine qui ont recours a l’automédication ? \\


{\let\clearpage\relax\chapter*{Hypothèse de recherche}}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Hypothèse de recherche}
La prévalence des étudiants en médecine qui optent pour l’automédication par les antibiotiques est élevée. \\

{\let\clearpage\relax\chapter*{Devis de recherche}}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Devis de recherche }
On menera une étude de type CAP (Connaissance-Aptitude-Pratiques).


L'enquête CAP est un outil stratégique d’identification du 
besoin éducationnel d’une cible spécifique. 

Elle évalue trois 
points : 
\begin{enumerate}
\item le niveau de la connaissance complète,
\item les attitudes 
motivant les comportements
\item les pratiques préventives et 
de prise en charge des populations cibles. 
\end{enumerate}
Il s’agit d’une étude mixte,(qualitative et quantitative) menée 
dans une visée analytique. Les résultats sont catégorisés, 
qualifiés ou quantifiés, selon l’objectif poursuivi.
La démarche de recherche est holistique, car elle doit 
concilier les 3 composantes du comportement des 
populations : la composante cognitive, la composante 
émotionnelle et la composante conative. 

En effet, l’action 
composée de ces composantes psychologiques résume la 
difficulté que rencontrent les populations à relier les 
connaissances reçues avec l’adoption réelle de 
comportements sains, et révèle de fait, toute l’importance des 
enquêtes CAP dans la santé publique. 
\chapter*{Population de recherche}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Population de recherche}
\subsection*{1. Population cible: }
\addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{1. Population cible }
Les étudiants de la faculté de la médecine de Sousse
\subsection*{2. Population source: }
\addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{2. Population source }
Les étudiants de la faculté de médecine de Sousse inscrits pour l’année universitaire 2021-2022

\subsection*{3. Critères d'inclusion: }
\addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{3. critères d'inclusion }
$\bullet$ L’étudiant est inscrit dans la faculté pour l’année universitaire 2021-2022.


$\bullet$ La volonté de participation.




\subsection*{4. Critères d'exclusion: }
\addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{4. critères d'exclusion }

$\bullet$ La non acceptation de participer.


\subsection*{5. Taille d'échantillon: }
\addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{5. Taille d'échantillon }

$\bullet$ La prévalence d’automédication par les antibiotiques est estimée à :


                     la marge d’erreur est : $5\%$
                     
                     
                     la précision désirée est: $5\%$
                     

Donc la taille d’échantillon nécessaire est estimée à :
$$N=\frac{z^2\times p\times q}{i^2}=\frac{1.96^2\times 0.26\times(1-0.26)}{0.05^2}=296$$

\subsection*{6. Type d'échantillage: }
\addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{6. Type d'échantillage }

Echantillonnage non probabiliste de volontaires.


Les unités statistiques seront les étudiants de la faculté de médecine de Sousse de premier et deuxième cycle inscrits pour l’année universitaire 2021-2022.


L’instrument de mesure sera un questionnaire distribué sur le réseau social Facebook dans les groupes des 5 promotions et dans le groupe officiel de la faculté entre le 9 février et le 9 mars 2022.
\begin{enumerate}


   \item  Le questionnaire se lance le 9 février 2022 a 23:59.
   \item  le questionnaire sera relancé chaque jour sur le fil d’actualité.
    \item  Le questionnaire se ferme le 9 mars 2022 a 23:59.
\end{enumerate}

\chapter*{Définition des variables}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Définition des variables}

 \begin{enumerate}
    
    \item \begin{large}
\underline{Automédication par les antibiotiques :}
\end{large}\\

 c’est le recours aux antibiotiques sans ordonnance pour soigner des pathologies.\\
 
 \item \begin{large}
\underline{L’étudiant en médecine :}
\end{large}\\

c’est l’unité statistique.  
\end{enumerate} 

\let\clearpage\relax\chapter*{Instrument de mesure}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Instrument de mesure}
\begin{center}


\includegraphics[page=1,width = 1\linewidth]{formulaire.pdf} \\[1.5cm]
\includegraphics[page=2,width = 1\linewidth]{formulaire.pdf} \\[1.5cm]
\includegraphics[page=3,width = 1\linewidth]{formulaire.pdf} \\[1.5cm]
\includegraphics[page=4,width = 1\linewidth]{formulaire.pdf} \\[1.5cm]


\end{center}






\chapter*{Echeancier:}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Echeancier}
\begin{table}[H]
\centering
\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{%
\begin{tabular}{|l|ll|ll|ll|}
\hline
                              & \multicolumn{2}{l|}{Janvier}                                             & \multicolumn{2}{l|}{février}                  & \multicolumn{2}{l|}{mars}                                                \\ \hline
Revue de la littérature       & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{009901}} &                          & \multicolumn{2}{l|}{}                         & \multicolumn{2}{l|}{}                                                    \\ \hline
Revue du protocole            & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{}                         & \cellcolor[HTML]{009901} & \multicolumn{2}{l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{FFFFFF}} & \multicolumn{2}{l|}{}                                                    \\ \hline
Questionnaire                 & \multicolumn{2}{l|}{}                                                    & \multicolumn{2}{l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{009901}} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{009901}} &                          \\ \hline
Saisie et analyse des données & \multicolumn{2}{l|}{}                                                    & \multicolumn{2}{l|}{}                         & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{}                         & \cellcolor[HTML]{009901} \\ \hline
Rédaction du rapport final    & \multicolumn{2}{l|}{}                                                    & \multicolumn{2}{l|}{}                         & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{}                         & \cellcolor[HTML]{009901} \\ \hline
\end{tabular}%
}
\end{table}


{\let\clearpage\relax\chapter*{Pertinence de la recherche:}}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Pertinenece de la recherche}



Les résultats correspondent a l’orientation des exigences et aux questions soulèves par le problème.


Les résultats obtenus nous permettent de savoir les comportements attitudes et pratiques des étudiants en médecine  a propos de l’automédication par les antibiotiques.


Les résultats obtenus nous permettent de déterminer les facteurs prédisposant l’utilisation des antibiotiques par les étudiants en médecine. \\






{\let\clearpage\relax\chapter*{Considérations éthiques}}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Considérations éthiques}




$\bullet$ Accord du comité éthique de la faculté de médecine.


$\bullet$ Accord préalable des personnes.

$\bullet$ La volonté de participation.






























































































\begin{thebibliography}{KNU90}
\bibitem{1} A.H.M.A. Faqihi, S.F. Sayed,
Self-medication practice with analgesics (NSAIDs and acetaminophen), and antibiotics among nursing undergraduates in University College Farasan Campus, Jazan University, KSA,
Annales Pharmaceutiques Françaises,
Volume 79, Issue 3,
2021,Pages 275-285 ISSN 0003-4509, https://doi.org/10.1016/j.pharma.2020.10.012.
(https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0003450920301280)




\bibitem{2}Mandal, N.K. , Rauniyar, G.P. , Rai, D.S. , Panday, D.R. , Kushwaha, R., Agrawal, S.K. and Regmee, P. 2020. Self-medication Practice of Antibiotics among Medical and Dental Undergraduate Students in a Medical College in Eastern Nepal: A Descriptive Cross-sectional Study. Journal of Nepal Medical Association. 58, 225 (May 2020), 328–323. DOI:https://doi.org/10.31729/jnma.4914.


\bibitem{3} Chen J, Sidibi AM, Shen X, Dao K, Maiga A, Xie Y, Hesketh T. Lack of antibiotic knowledge and misuse of antibiotics by medical students in Mali: a cross-sectional study. Expert Rev Anti Infect Ther. 2021 Jun;19(6):797-804. doi: 10.1080/14787210.2021.1857731. Epub 2020 Dec 17. PMID: 33251896.


\end{thebibliography}

\end{document} ```
````

Comment: @DavidCarlisle thank you david, i would like you if possible to help me again : now the bibliography section doesn't appear anymore

Comment: unrrlate but why `$\bullet$ ...` everywhere instead of using an itemized list?

Comment: you shoule never do `\let\clearpage\relax`  as it is quite likely to break latex, what is the intention?

Comment: because i have little text to write

Comment: about the bullet part ; i dont know how to use it in an itemized list instead of the usual "-"

Comment: If you do not want your headings to start a new page use `article` not `report` and use `\section` not `\chapter`

Comment: please try to use more reasonable example documents which should be as small as possible and only have lines _needed_ to show the problem you posted 816 !!! lines of code but we can not run it as it gives error `! Package pdftex.def Error: File \`fms.jpg' not found: using draft setting.` then multiple `! Package pdftex.def Error: File \`formulaire.pdf' not found: using draft setting` so we can not know what page breaking you are seeing

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/133889/discussion-between-karaa-abdelaziz-and-david-carlisle).